# conditional 'or' in nhibernate where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm working on an nhibernate query where I need to select all records in a table where the id matches any id in an array I have.

so I have `int[] ids` and I need a

```
.Where(x => x.id == ids[0]
 || x.id == ids[1]
 || x.id == ids[2]
```

etc... but the array can have a variable number of ids in it. What's the correct way of doing this?

I'm not sure what to search either, otherwise I would've found something on google probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IsIn()`:

```
.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Id).IsIn(ids);
```

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate can convert a Contains call to [In query](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/interactive_sql_tutorial/sql_in.php) in SQL.

```
.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.id));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with:

```
.Where(x => Array.IndexOf(i, x.Id)>-1 );
```

**Pros:**

+NHibernate is not using sql - like `IsIn()`

+Is 3x faster than `Cointains()`

here u find code to test it

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] i = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 


        for (int j= 0; 1000000 > j; j++)
        {
            int pos = Array.IndexOf(i, 5);
            if (pos > -1)
            { }
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        Stopwatch stopwatch2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int j = 0; 1000000 > j; j++)
        {
            bool pos = i.Contains(5);
            if (pos)
            { }
        }
        stopwatch2.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        Console.Read();
    }
```

[image]